# Hash returning a dynamic value

Tags: ruby, hash

I ran across this snippet in RubyDocs:

```
class Interpreter
  ...
  Dispatcher = {
    "a" => instance_method(:do_a),
    "d" => instance_method(:do_d),
    "e" => instance_method(:do_e),
    "v" => instance_method(:do_v)
  }
  ...
end
```

Is there any way to define the hash `Dispatcher` using a variable to represent the key and the value as below?

```
"#{var}" => instance_method(:do_#{var})
```

Comment: @sawa Sorry to see that you deleted your answer.

Comment: I suggest using a method rather than a hash: `class D; def dispatcher(m) send("to_#{m}") end; def to_a() puts "hi" end; end;
D.new.dispatcher("a") => "hi"`.

Comment: Hi @CarySwoveland - the question was edited and thereby lost some context. I'm taking this snippet from the following page: [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method), where the assignment of a hash has the advantage of being extensible in other ways.

Comment: Yes, I saw that (the direct link being [Module#instance_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method)). Incidentally, if you don't like edits that are done to *your* question, rollback or re-edit.

Comment: Good to know. I don't think the question loses anything essential from the edit, but I thought the wider context might help respond to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dispatcher = Hash.new do |k, h| h[k] = instance_method "do_#{k}" end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%w[d a v e].each_with_object({}) do |a, o|
  o[a] = instance_method("do_#{a}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dispatcher = {}
self.instance_methods.grep(/do_*/).each do |method|
    Dispatcher[method.to_s.sub "do_", ""] = instance_method(method)
end
```

It iterates through all instance methods that match the "do_" prefix and adds it to the `Dispatcher` hash.

Comment: Minor, but you don't need `self`.